# Windows Phone 7 - Function for ListBox button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox

I have list of items in ListBox.
All the items have buttons.
I want to show the selected items name when I click the button inside the ListBox (Not the list box items).

My Xaml:-

```
<ListBox SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex,Mode=TwoWay}"  
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudent, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="374" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding StudentDetails,Mode=TwoWay}" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,6,0,0" Name="listBox1" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="476" BorderBrush="#00410D0D">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding EventPageCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Gray" Padding="5" BorderThickness="1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Wheat" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Image Name="ListPersonImage" Source="{Binding PersonImage}" 
                               Height="100" Width="100" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                    </Border>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Name="firstName" Width="200" 
                               Foreground="White" Margin="10,10,0,0" 
                               FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />

                    <Button Height="80" Width="80" Command="{Binding addPerson}" 
                            DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=listBox1}">
                        <Button.Background>
                            <ImageBrush 
                                ImageSource="/NewExample;component/Images/icon_increase.png" />
                        </Button.Background>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Here when I click the 'addPerson' Button it should show the selected items name.
Now I have write the coding for List box 'SelectedItmes'.

My ViewModel:-

```
 private MVVMListBoxModel selectedStudent;
public MVVMListBoxModel SelectedStudent
{
    get { return selectedStudent; }
    set
    {
        if (selectedStudent == value)
            return;
        selectedStudent = value;
        MessageBox.Show("Selected Item==>" + selectedStudent.FirstName + " Selected Index==>" + SelectedIndex);
        if (SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            var rootFrame = (App.Current as App).RootFrame;
            rootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
}
```

Here I can show the selected Name when I click the list box items.
But now I want to show when I click the button.
Is it possible to show the items when I click the button?

Now I have tried like this:-

```
public ReactiveAsyncCommand addPerson { get; set; }

public MVVMListBoxViewModel()
{
    addPerson = new ReactiveAsyncCommand();
    addPerson.Subscribe(x =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button Clicked..!!");
            ListBox listbox = (ListBox)sender;
            ListBoxEventsModel items = (ListBoxEventsModel)listbox.SelectedItem;
            MessageBox.Show("Selected Name" + items.ToString());
    });
}
```

But here I can not show the selected items.
Please let me any idea to solve this issue.

Comment: Please post the declaration of `addPerson` is it a field or a property?

Comment: Hi @Verdsrobert. I have add the `addPerson` declaration in my original question.

Comment: I know that what I'm about to say is not much MVVM but just to test that your command is bound, you could subscribe to Loaded event on Button and check that it's Command Property is set and that its value is equal to your addPerson ReactiveAsyncCommand.

Comment: Hi @verdesrobert.. Can you give me any example?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that your code is working 
Make some tests like this:

```
<Button Tap="btnTestCommand_Tap" Height="80" Width="80" Command="{Binding addPerson}" 
        DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=listBox1}">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/NewExample;component/Images/icon_increase.png" />
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Code behind:

```
private void btnTestCommand_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn=sender as Button;
    var command = btn.Command;
    MessageBox.Show("Entering Command Check\n DataContext is of type: "+btn.DataContext.GetType().Name);

    if(command !=null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Command is not null");
        if(command is ReactiveAsyncCommand)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Command is of ReactiveAsyncCommand type");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @verdesrobert. Thanks for reply. This code is not working. And also I want write this function in `ViewModel`. Any other idea?

Comment: Please be more detailed about "This code is not working"

Comment: Hi @verdesrobert.. It showing my class name. I have try with dii attributes also. It is not showing the List Items name.

Comment: Try moving DataContext before Command in your Button XAML definition

Comment: Ok.. Done.. **<Button DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=listBox1}" Tap="Button_Tap" Command="{Binding addPerson}" Height="80" Width="80" >**

Comment: What is the result now?