# WP7 - How to get the list box items from ViewModel?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, mvvm, listbox

I am trying to get the selected name from list box when I click the list box button.

My XAML page:-

```
    <ListBox Name="MyListBox"  Height="733" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentDetails,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,35,0,0" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="476">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Gray" Padding="5" BorderThickness="1">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Border BorderBrush="Wheat" BorderThickness="1">
                                    <Image  Name="ListPersonImage" Source="{Binding PersonImage}" Height="100" Width="100" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                </Border>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Name="firstName" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" Name="lastName" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="-200,50,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" Name="age" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />


   <Button Command="{Binding buttonClick}" DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=MyListBox}" Margin="-200,0,0,0" Height="80" Width="80">         
                                    <Button.Background>
                                        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" >
                                            <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                                                <BitmapImage UriSource="/NewExample;component/Images/icon_increase.png" />
                                            </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                                        </ImageBrush>
                                    </Button.Background>                                   
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Xaml.Cs:-

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button myButton = sender as Button;
            ListBoxWithButtonModel dataObject = myButton.DataContext as ListBoxWithButtonModel;
            int index = MyListBox.Items.IndexOf(dataObject);
            MessageBox.Show("Button Clicked" + dataObject.FirstName);
        }
```

Here I can get the selected name when I click the button. But this same thing I want to do from my View Model. Please help me to get the selected name from ViewModel.

I have try like this.

```
 listButton = new ReactiveAsyncCommand();
            listButton.Subscribe(x =>
            {

                ListBoxWithButtonModel dataObject = listButton.DataContext as ListBoxWithButtonModel;
                //int index = MyListBox.Items.IndexOf(dataObject);
                MessageBox.Show("Button Clicked" + dataObject.FirstName);

            });
```

But here I am getting error DataContext does not contain ReactiveAsycCommand.
Please help me to solve this problem.

My ViewModel:-

```
public ReactiveAsyncCommand buttonClick { get; set; }

public ListBoxWithButtonViewModel()
        {
            buttonClick = new ReactiveAsyncCommand();
            buttonClick.Subscribe(x =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("TEst");
            });
        }
```

Herer I can show the message box. But how to get the selected item here??

My Another try.

```
 public RelayCommand<ListBoxWithButtonModel> ItemSelectedCommand { get; private set; }

 public ListBoxWithButtonViewModel()
        {
            ItemSelectedCommand = new RelayCommand<ListBoxWithButtonModel>(ItemSelected);
        }

        private void ItemSelected(ListBoxWithButtonModel myItem)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Testing");
            if (null != myItem)
                MessageBox.Show("Name==>" + myItem.FirstName);
        }
```

Here also I can not get the selected item. Please give me any idea to resolve this problem.

Comment: Where in the viewmodel you want to access selected name?

Comment: @har07.. I have updated my question. Please review that and give me solution.

Comment: What is the problem what your updated code, Is it `myItem` always `null`?

Comment: Yes.. It is always null..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't stated clearly but I suspect the problem is `myItem` parameter always `null` because you never pass the parameter in XAML.

Use `CommandParameter` property to pass parameter for your `Command`, for example :

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.ItemSelectedCommand, ElementName=MyListBox}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
        Margin="-200,0,0,0" Height="80" Width="80">         
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" >
            <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                <BitmapImage UriSource="/NewExample;component/Images/icon_increase.png" />
            </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
        </ImageBrush>
    </Button.Background>                                   
</Button>
```

Comment: Can't see what's wrong with my code, it worked fine for me. Make sure you update all binding within the `Button` following this answer.

Comment: Hi @har07.. I can not get the answer. As per your instruction I have changed my XAML. '<Button  Command="{Binding DataContext.buttonClick, ElementName=MyListBox}" 
CommandParameter="{Binding ItemSelectedCommand}" Margin="-200,0,0,0" Height="80" Width="80">`. But no improvement. Please let me know where I did mistake.

Comment: Hi @har07.. I have upload a sample project. If it is possible please just modify that?. Sorry if I am ask anything wrong.. [https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9CBE7976CDD57B70%21191]

Comment: Hi @har07.. Did you see my example??

Comment: Just tried but I can't get the project, the link seems expired already

Comment: No.. Yesterday only I have created and uploaded that project.

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxedZzp29FnBelRrcDQzMzJWak0/edit?usp=sharing] .. Please try this.. Sorry for the disturb..

Comment: "**This item might not exist or is no longer available.** This item might have been deleted, expired, or you might not have permission to view it. Contact the owner of this item for more information. "

Comment: I just checked your project, you should've bound the `Command` to `ItemSelectedCommand` property as opposed to `buttonClick` property. Updated my answer to show complete binding set up for the `Button`.

Comment: Thank you @har07..!! Last 3 months I am searching for this solution.. Really happy.. Thank you..!!

Answer (score 0):

Set the `DataContext` to the button.

```
<Button DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=MyListBox}"
Height="80"
Width="80"
Command="{Binding listButton}">
<Button.Background>
<ImageBrush ImageSource="/NewExample;component/Images/icon_increase.png"
            Stretch="Fill" />
</Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Take a look here [Windows Phone 7 - Function for ListBox button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288635)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @Vijay How are you binding your viewmodel here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StudentDetails obj = MyListBox.SelectedItem;
    MessageBox.Show(obj.FirstName);
}
```